# SecurityHub Insufficient Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-security-hub

I have a multi account organization with AWS SSO. I messed with securityhub a while back ago and would be able to enable/disable it. A year later I tried using it again but I cannot get into it. I've tried accessing it with my root account, and even created a full access IAM user to test outside of SSO and that doesn't work either. I get this same issue with GuardDuty too. I don't have any SCP's that would be blocking this, and I've tried using the AWS provided securityhub policies too.

What else would be blocking access to securityhub?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, my system clock was off and was resolved by enabling a time sync setting. If all permissions look good, this error can prompt because of a system clock issue as well.